# Saving 8 booleans into 1 byte

Tags: c++, serialization, save

I'm coding a program writing down to a file a large bool area (usually around 512*512 bool variables). It would make great use of saving it in a smart way, I'm thinking about saving them 8 by 8, coding these 8 booleans into one byte of the form:

```
byte = bit0 * boolean0 | ... | bit7 * boolean7
```

But I'm not sure how to handle this conversion, though I know to write and read a file byte by byte.

I'm using C++, I've no background in CS but this seems close to the topic of serialization though everything I searched on the subject is really unclear to me. Has it already been implemented, or this there a really simple way to implement it? (I meant saving as much CPU time as possible, my program will write and open millions of these files per instance)

Cheers.

Edit:

With the help of Sean (thank you btw!) I managed to get a bit further but it is still not working, a test of the data after saving and reading tells me that it gets corrupted (as in not reconstructed correctly and so not identical to the initial data) somewhere in the writing, reading  or both...

My code will probably help.

Here are the writing lines:

```
    typedef char byte;
    ofstream ofile("OUTPUT_FILE");
    for(int i=0;i<N/8;i++){
    byte encoded = 0;
    for(int j=0; j<8; j++){
        byte bit = (byte)(tab[(i*8+j)/h][(i*8+j)%h]==1);
        encoded = (encoded << 1) | bit;
        }           
    ofile << encoded;
    }
```

and the reading lines:

```
for(int i=0;i<N/8;i++){ //N is the total number of entries I have in my final array
    temp = ifile.get(); //reading the byte in a char
    for(int j=0; j<8; j++){ // trying to read each bits in there
        if(((temp >> j) & 1) ? '1' : '0' ){
            tab[(i*8+j)/h][(i*8+j)%h]=1;
            }
        else{
            tab[(i*8+j)/h][(i*8+j)%h]=-1; //my programs manipulates +1 (TRUE) and -1 (FALSE) making most of the operations easier
            }
        }
    }
ifile.close();
```

Edit2:

I finally managed to do using the bitset<8> objects, much clearer to me than to manipulate bits inside char. I'll probably update my post later with my working code. I'm still concerned with efficiency, is it much quicker to work with than to bitset do you think?

Comment: I think C++ bitset is what you want: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/

Comment: vector<bool> also does that

Comment: @dsi I think OP is looking to save space. `bool` normally takes up one byte, doesn't it?

Comment: @Lmis no, vector<bool> specialization packs booleans similar to bitset, while allowing for dynamic resize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can encode the `bool`s to an `int` in a loop like this:

```
bool flags[8];

// populate flags from somewhere

byte encoded=0;

for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
{
  byte bit = (byte)flags[i];
  encoded = (encoded << 1) | bit;
}
```

The code uses the fact that casting a `bool` to a number yields 1 for `true` and o for `false`.

Alternatively you can unroll it:

```
byte encoded = 0;
encoded |= ((byte)flags[0]) << 7;
encoded |= ((byte)flags[1]) << 6;
encoded |= ((byte)flags[2]) << 5;
encoded |= ((byte)flags[3]) << 4;
encoded |= ((byte)flags[4]) << 3;
encoded |= ((byte)flags[5]) << 2;
encoded |= ((byte)flags[6]) << 1;
encoded |= ((byte)flags[7]);
```

To convert the byte back to an array of flags you can do something like this:

```
bool flags[8];
byte encoded= /* some value */

for(int i=0, i<8; i++)
{
  bool flag=(bool)(encoded & 1);
  flags[7-i]=flag;
  encoded>>=1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works like at charm at saving the file, through I'd add that you need to add the `typedef char byte;` somewhere in your code.

Comment: Also I still haven't figured out how to do the reverse step and read the byte from the file to 8 booleans.

Comment: @Liam - you should use `typedef unsigned char byte` just to be sure

Comment: @Liam - I've added an example to show how to reverse the step

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need to determine the size of you bit array at runtime, you can use std::bitset

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset